# My single layer perceptrone is not working

Tags: c#, machine-learning, neural-network, perceptron

Here is code.

```
public class Adaline
{
    private int _layer;
    public int Layer { get { return _layer; } }
    private int _epoch;
    public int Epoch { get { return _epoch; } }
    private double _error;
    public double Error { get { return _error; } }

    private double[] _weights;

    public Adaline(int layer)
    {
        _layer = layer;
        _weights = new double[layer];
        Reset();
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < _layer; i++)
            _weights[i] = r.NextDouble() - 0.5;
        _error = 1;
    }

    public void Train(BasicTrainSet<double> trainset, double learnRate)
    {
        double ers = 0;
        for(int p = 0; p < trainset.DataCount; p++)
        {
            double result = Compute(trainset.Input[p], true);
            double error = trainset.Output[p] - result;

            for (int i = 0; i < _weights.Length; i++)
            {
                _weights[i] += error * trainset.Input[p][i] * learnRate;
            }

            ers += Math.Abs(error);
        }
        _epoch++;
        _error = ers;
    }

    public double Compute(double[] input, bool quan)
    {
        double result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < _layer; i++)
            result += Math.Tanh(_weights[i] * input[i]);
        //double result = _weights.Zip(input, (a, b) => Math.Tanh(a * b)).Sum();
        return quan ? (result >= 0 ? 1 : 0) : result;
    }
}
```

When I tried to train and gate like this, it works like this.
[Up four results are from this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5O75n.png)
This is pretty weird, because there is not any problem with algorithm.
Weights are getting bigger and bigger. Where did i mistake?

Comment: Can you show how you train your perceptron? I mean code that executes your training logic.

Comment: You are applying tanh after each accumulation operation. You need to accumulate first THEN apply tanh after.

Comment: @rayryeng thanks, now works very well. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code to compute the output of each neuron, you aren't applying the activation function correctly.  You need to find the dot product between the weights and the inputs into each neuron **then** apply the activation function after. You are applying the activation function after each weighted accumulation, which is not correct.

Accumulate, then apply the activation function:

```
public double Compute(double[] input, bool quan)
{
    double result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < _layer; i++)
        result += _weights[i] * input[i]; // Change - accumulate first
    result = Math.Tanh(result); // Change - now apply activation function

    return quan ? (result >= 0 ? 1 : 0) : result;
}
```

Comment: I used linq for shorter code.
`double result = Sigmoid.LogSigmoid(_weights.Zip(input, (a, b) => (a * b)).Sum() + _biasWeight);`